# Convert Codeigniter .htaccess file to equivallent web.config file for IIS 8

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I have locally developed project using **codeigniter framework and Xampp apache server**,
url redirection is on and rewrite rules are defined in .htaccess file and working properly, here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

now suddenly client requirement has changed and he wants all windows environment, instead of apache he suggested to use IIS, so i have to move to IIS. Same project with little modifications is running and redirecting default controller which is defined in routes.php file but my other redirections are not working. I searched and found that .htaccess file does not work on IIS need to convert .htaccess file to web.config however i  tried to convert my .htaccess to **web.config** as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="MyRule">
                <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
             </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**But this does work,giving following error:**

**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**

> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification      BeginRequest
>
> Handler       Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x8007000d

Config Error

> Config File           \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myproject\web.config
>   Requested URL      http://localhost:80/myproject/
>   Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myproject\
>   Logon Method       Not yet determined
>   Logon User     Not yet determined

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:

I tried in different ways with different code but it is **showing same error every time,**please help

Comment: hey...solved,i did not have permission to web.config file...:)